# product metric is a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Question:
>
> Given metric space $\left ( X,d \right )$ and $\left ( Y,e, \right )$,
> define the product metric on $X \times Y by f\left ( \left ( x_{1},y_{1} \right ), \left ( x_{2},y_{2} \right )\right ):=max\left \{ d\left ( x_{1},x_{2} \right ),e\left ( y_{1},y_{2} \right ) \right \}$

Prove that f is a metric on $X \times Y$

Any hint or help is appreciated to kickstart my attempt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A metric is any function that satisfies certain properties. Have you tried to show that these properties hold? See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only non trivial thing to verify is triangular inequality. Let $(x_0,y_0)$, $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ be points of $X\times Y$. Then $$f((x_0,y_0),(x_2,y_2))=\max\{d(x_0,x_2),e(y_0,y_2)\}\leq\max\{d(x_0,x_1)+d(x_1,x_2),e(y_0,y_1)+e(y_1,y_2)\}\leq\max\{d(x_0,x_1),e(y_0,y_1)\}+\max\{d(x_1,x_2),e(y_1,y_2)\},$$
which is what you need.